# Is there an easy way to map text into structured JSON objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dictionary, extract

I want to transform data, out of a text file, into a structured JSON object, based on a template.

The template looks like the following

```
Hello my name is {name}!
```

The text file contains following input

```
My name is Max
```

The expectation is now to get a JSON object which looks like this:

```
{
 "name": "Max"
}
```

Is there an easy way to handle all this? For instance an npm package.

Thank you!

Comment: Your template and input mismatch is it a mistake?

Comment: Looks like a parsing thing. TS-ANTLR  AND ANTLR unless you know your subset language is regular but then you would have just hacked it with regular expressions anyway

Comment: @StevenSpungin op wants to do other way around, get data out of template

Comment: @KonradLinkowski: Input is correct and Yes - I want to do the other way around :-)

Comment: As a start, you could convert your phrase to a regex, and replace your curlys with parenthesis groups.  That would match your field.  You would need to do some escaping in circumstances.

Comment: Why does `My name is Max` match `Hello my name is {name}!`? It seems like the template is asking to see something that doesn't exist in the string `My name is Max`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to get the value of name.

```js
let str = "My name is Max";

let name = str.match(/My name is (.*)/)[1];

let obj = { name };

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! But at the end I want to parse a lot of more data. Final goal is to parse a text file which contains a whole OO-Class in different languages and I think multiple REGEX is not the way to go. But thank you.

Comment: for that you can easily use regex too. It'd just be a little more complicated. You can mark my answer correct / give it up vote if it was helpful, thanks.